# Huge difference when selecting on partitioned data

Tags: sql, apache-spark, select

I have a huge table partitioned by `date` and `hour`:

```
ID ... dates(string) hour(string)
1  ... 2020-11-19    0
2  ... 2020-11-19    0
3  ... 2020-11-19    1
...
```

When I run `select * from tbl where dates = '2020-11-19' and hour = '1'`, it is pretty fast.

I have another table which just stores a timestamp

```
ts(timestamp)
2020/11/19 01:32:13.350 GMT+08:00
```

When I run

```
select * from tbl where dates = (select date(ts) from ts_tbl) and hour = (select hour(ts) from ts_tbl)
```

this is very slow and I found this statement will scan the whole table.

I expected those two statements should have the same performance.

By the way, I'm running spark sql.

Comment: what is base of your expectations??

Comment: Those two statements are selecting on the same partitioned data.

Comment: this is not how sql works. you run atleast three `select` clause in second query.  of course it will be slower. But if the table doen't have huge amount of data and have proper index usually the difference is not that huge.

Comment: Hi - as a minimum you would need to provide the EXPLAIN PLANs for both these statements in order for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: The second version is not pruning the partitions.  You need to take. a different approach.